# PTR DWORD in nim lang

Tags: pointers, nim-lang

what is the problem of This Code:

```
import winim


let CurrentProcessID = GetCurrentProcessId()
var SessionID :DWORD
let result1 = ProcessIdToSessionId(CurrentProcessID,cast [ptr DWORD](SessionID))
echo SessionID
```

Compile Command:

```
nim c -d=danger -d=mingw -d=strip --passc=-flto --passl=-flto --opt=size --app=console --cpu=amd64 --out=test.exe test.nim
```

OutPut in Windows10:

```
0
```

but the Correct answer is:

```
1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProcessIdToSessionId needs a pointer to the variable to write to, but you're passing the value of the variable *itself* as a pointer, that's why it fails.

Correct code would be like this (untested):

```
import winim

let CurrentProcessID = GetCurrentProcessId()
var SessionID: DWORD
let result1 = ProcessIdToSessionId(CurrentProcessID, addr SessionID)
echo SessionID
```